# Permanent gaierror 'Temporary failure in name resolution' after running for a few hours

Tags: python, urllib, httplib, getaddrinfo, python-sockets

I have a long running python script, launched with upstart. This script makes quite a lot of requests. Everything works well at first, however after a few hours I start permanently getting the following error for each request:

```
  File "/opt/a/a-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/client.py", line 119, in request
  File "/opt/a/a-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/http_core.py", line 420, in request
  File "/opt/a/a-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/http_core.py", line 489, in _http_request
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 931, in endheaders
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 794, in _send_output
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 756, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1134, in connect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

This is not a problem with name resolution or DNS, because a simple restart of the application fixes this problem.

I've tried both Python 2.6 a 2.7 and the same situation occurs.

I'm running `Linux 2.6.35-30-virtual #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 11 18:26:36 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

There have been a few posts with this problem, but none with a straightforward explanation or solution:

- https://github.com/ggstuart/greenview/issues/4
- [Permanent 'Temporary failure in name resolution' after running for a number of hours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8356517/1116061)

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens when you get in a "too many open files" condition. Next time this happens, try to see how many file descriptors your script has open.

Comment: Been getting it recently, only 394 file descriptors open across entire system (`lsof | wc -l`).

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that /etc/resolv.conf is only read at python startup. To force a refresh of the resolve table, you can run this (on Linux):

```
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
res_init = libc.__res_init
res_init()
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to *this* question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.