# 'urllib2.URLError'(<urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>

Tags: web2py, urllib

I have a web2py app installed which is served by Apache. After months of successful deployment, the website suddenly stops functioning with the error:

```
class 'urllib2.URLError'(urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

I tried restarting the app and apache but it did not help. What are the possible causes for such an event to happen?

The system worked fine after a reboot.

Comment: Seems like a error of urllib2 when it have many connections waiting to close, this question already was asked here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356517/permanent-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-after-running-for-a-number-of-h

Comment: More info about urllib2 here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html